# Greasemonkey script seems to ignore setInterval?

Tags: javascript, onclick, greasemonkey, setinterval

I'm trying to make a toy script in GreaseMonkey that will cause my screen to repeatedly jump to the top of my screen when I click a button, and stop jumping when I click the button again.

This is my code:

```
var perpetualScroll = function () {
    var scrolling = false;

    var scroll = function () {
        if (scrolling) {
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        }
    };

    var scrollDiv = document.createElement("div");
    scrollDiv.id = "topScroll0x2a";
    scrollDiv.innerHTML = '<a class="topScroll" onclick="scrolling = !scrolling;" style="display:block; position:fixed; bottom: 1em; right: 1em; color:#fff; background-color:#000; padding:.5em;" href="#">Start scroll</a>';
    document.body.appendChild(scrollDiv);

    var intervalId = window.setInterval(scroll, 50);
};

perpetualScroll();
```

When I click the button in the lower corner the script creates, it does jump to the top of the screen, but doesn't continue to perpetually do so.

I'm really new to Javascript and GreaseMonkey, so I'm not quite sure what the problem is.  I suspect it might be due to issues in the onclick part of the link, but if it is, I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing `onclick` like that will not work like you expect. Your `innerHTML` is just a string, so JS has no idea that it is scoped within your `perpetualScroll` function.

`onclick` handlers that are strings are evaluated in the global scope, so what you have is equivalent to this:

```
 window.scrolling = !window.scrolling;
```

The `scrolling` variable you want is different.

You should create an actual function like this:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.className = (a.className || "") + ' topScroll';
a.style.display = 'block';
a.style.position = 'fixed';
a.style.bottom = '1em';
a.style.right = '1em';
a.style.color = '#FFF';
a.style.backgroundColor = '#000';
a.style.padding = '0.5em';
a.href = '#';
a.onclick = function(e){
    scrolling = !scrolling;
    return false;
};
scrollDiv.appendChild(a);
```

Obviously setting that CSS is terrible, so you should really put that in a separate stylesheet anyway.

Comment: Ohh, that looks like a much better way of doing it.  I didn't know you could do stuff like `a.style.blah`, thanks!  

(And yeah, I'd make a separate stylesheet, but I'm feeling lazy :D )